# XPATH Select All Attributes attr Except One On Specific Element elem

Tags: xpath

I was selecting all attributes `id` and everything was going nicely then one day requirements changed and now I have to select all except one!

Given the following example:

```
<root> 
  <structs id="123"> 
    <struct> 
      <comp> 
        <data id="asd"/> 
      </comp> 
    </struct> 
  </structs> 
</root>
```

I want to select all attributes `id` except the one at `/root/structs/struct/comp/data`

Please note that the Xml could be different. 
Meaning, what I really want is: given any Xml tree, I want to select all attributes `id` except the one on element `/root/structs/struct/comp/data`

I tried the following:

`//@id[not(ancestor::struct)]` It kinda worked but I want to provide a full xpath to the ancestor axis which I couldn't

`//@id[not(contains(name(), 'data'))]` It didn't work because name selector returns the name of the underlying node which is the attribute not its parent element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should achieve what you're describing:

```
//@id[not(parent::data/parent::comp/parent::struct/parent::structs/parent::root)]
```

As you can see, it simply checks from bottom to top whether the `id` attribute's parent matches the path `root/structs/struct/comp/data`.

I think this should be sufficient for your needs, but it does not 100% ensure that the parent is at the path `/root/structs/struct/comp/data` because it could be, for example, at the path `/someOtherHigherRoot/root/structs/struct/comp/data`. I'm guessing that's not a possible scenario in your XML structure, but if you had to check for that, you could do this:

```
//@id[not(parent::data/parent::comp/parent::struct/parent::structs/parent::root[not(parent::*)])]
```

Comment: `root` is always the root Xml element
Thanks a lot for your answer! I will test on different cases and then report back here